# How to implement shopping cart functionality when creating REST web service?

Tags: java, spring, rest, jakarta-ee

I am creating an app store for digital services. I want the user to be able to choose multiple products with different quantity before confirming the order and pay for the services. This requires that something keep state. From [REST Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer):

> Each request from any client contains all the information necessary to service the request, and session state is held in the client.

I got state that I need to keep somewhere, and I also have a flow. The flow I can mange, but it is the state that I don't understand how and where I should store. The user may add several products to a shopping cart before checking out.

I have thought of a endpoint like this where you post a `cart-item` object each time you want something.

```
POST /shopping-cart
```

But I shouldn't use HTTP sessions if I understand it right? I have seen someone saying to store it in database but would you use a in memory database then? When should i flush the database if the user doesn't confirm and pay? I could need some input on what I should do to keep it simple and RESTful.

I am using Spring 4.x and Java EE for the record.

Comment: I rather like it when my machine crashes and I go back to a website and find that my cart still has my stuff in it, so I vote for the database.  Many sites do persist shopping carts for a period of time such as 14 days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But I shouldn't use HTTP sessions if I understand it right?

Correct.

> I have seen someone saying to store it in database but would you use a in memory database then?

You should keep in in a disk-storage database. This allows you to add nodes to your server without having to worry about routing all requests from one client to the same node.

> When should i flush the database if the user doesn't confirm and pay?

That's a business decision.

Comment: Okey, so I create normal entities for shopping cart, shopping cart item and so on and persist it in the database as normal then?

Comment: And what do you do with shopping carts after the user have purchased the products? Delete it, or just mark it as paid?

Comment: remember one thing, never never never delete anything. Just set a flag: deleted. same for the purchase.. That's my point of view! :D

Comment: @LuckyLuke That is what I would suggest, yes. How long you hold the cart is also a business decision. I would probably implement it as one cart per user, with items removed and added to orders, rather than multiple carts, but I don't know anything about your project. :-)

Comment: @LMG "Never" is a long time. Eventually that kind of data will need to be migrated off the live database, either to backup or /dev/null.

Comment: @EricStein yep, I mean do not "hard" delete them from database. Keep them somewhere :P